# FMA instructions in compare function breaks strict weak ordering property

Tags: c++, gcc

The *C++ named requirement* [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) require that the compare functions follow the *[strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) property*. This is used for many standard library functions, for example [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Many modern-day CPUs support [Fused-Multiply-Add operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply%E2%80%93add) that computes `a + b * c` efficiently and without rounding the result of the multiplication. This implies that there are situations where the result from an FMA operation is different from separate multiply and add operations. FMA code generations for GCC is controlled by the [`-ffp-contract`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) flag and is enabled by default.

When the compiler generates FMA instructions in the compare function, there can arise a situation where the strict weak ordering property is (silently) no longer holding. **This can cause `std::sort` and other functions to fail and crash on runtime.**

Consider the following example:

```cpp
struct S {
    double a;
    double b;
};

bool compare(const volatile S& s1, const volatile S& s2) {  // Volatile to prevent compile-time computations
    return s1.a * s1.b - s2.a * s2.b < 0.0;
}

int main() {
    const double a = 1 + 0x1.0p-52;
    const double b = 1 - 0x1.0p-52;

    volatile S s1{a, b};  // Volatile to prevent compile-time computations
    volatile S s2{1.0, 1.0};

    std::cout << compare(s1, s2) << '\n';
    std::cout << compare(s2, s1) << '\n';
}
```

The expected output would be

```
1
0
```

However, on platforms supporting FMA (and when enabled, which again is default on GCC) the result is

```
0
0
```

(GCC 11.2, `-O3 -march=haswell`)

Clearly showing that the weak ordering property <del>is not enforced</del> does no longer hold.

**Why is this, potentially dangerous, feature enabled by default? What can be done to avoid this situation, besides disabling FMA code geneneration?**

Comment: not sure if I understand the question. `std::cout << ((s1.a*s1.b - s2.a*s2.b) == 0);` prints `1` with or without `-ffp-contract=off`  https://godbolt.org/z/vnz8qxnqo

Comment: You need to have optimization enabled and a suitable architecture. I.e. `-O3 -march=haswell`

Comment: my point is that the flags make no difference, anything i tried results in `(s1.a*s1.b - s2.a*s2.b) == 0`. Though, as I already mentioned, the question is beyond my understanding

Comment: I ran your code and switched between `-O3 -march=haswell` and `-O3 -march=haswell -ffp-contract=off` and saw differences in the output.

Answer (score 4):

The responsibility for ensuring a strict weak order lies with you, not the compiler. If you simply return `true` ignoring the arguments, it's obviously not a strict weak order. There's nothing a compiler can do to "enforce" the weak ordering.

Your code is of course not nearly as bad. It just contains a hidden assumption, namely that `s1.a * s1.b - s2.a * s2.b < 0.0;` if and only if `s1.a * s1.b < s2.a * s2.b;`. That holds for rational numbers, not for doubles. The reason is that `operator-` rounds to a `double` value. And only your version has an `operator-`

Again, when the implementation of the comparison is wrong, there is nothing a compiler can do to "enforce" the weak ordering.

Note that if you pass the option `-ffast-math`, then the compiler **may** turn `s1.a * s1.b - s2.a * s2.b < 0.0;` into `s1.a * s1.b < s2.a * s2.b;` or the other way around. It is an unsafe optimization, so the compiler won't do it until given permission. But without `-ffast-math`, the compiler will use exactly what you wrote, even if you *should* have used the other form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "Enforce" as a poorly chosen word from my side. I rather mean "does no longer hold". I will change it in my question.